# Preserving line-breaks when inserting using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, csv, c#-3.0, datatable, sqldataadapter

As part of a (C#) windows service I'm working on I'm pulling the contents of a CSV and dumping them into a single field on a single row in a DataTable. I'm using a DataTable because at times I may have more than one CSV to add.

The problem is, the SqlDataAdapter insert is removing the line-breaks and converting these into spaces.

So does anyone have any idea if it's possible to preserve line-breaks? Or am I just going to have to go with replacing the line-breaks with some other marker that I can then convert *back* into line-breaks later?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a misunderstanding on my part. The sql server output appeared to have no line-breaks but they *were* being preserved after all. Hope this helps someone else who's having a numpty moment like I was.